# How can I change the color used in my css files from codebehind?

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

Many of my `css` files (including bootstrap) use specified colors. I want to be able to change the main colors in one central place (such as the config pages I'm adding).

I have seen that `css` var's might be a thing soon but are currently not well supported.

Is there a more elegant way I can do this that my current idea of using the `css` files as templates which I will load with the color config on page load?

Comment: Are trying to do this in webform or mvc?

Comment: an easy solution is to have several css files for different themes (the colors), and then the codebehind / controller can decide which css file that you should used

Comment: I will do this in mvc.

Comment: @Farhad.b Did I answer you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) instead of CSS to have a variables and much more advantages.

If you combine using LESS with themes separated to different CSS files (as @Thorarins suggested), you'll get more powerful and maintainable.

LESS features:

1) **Variables**

```
LESS

@link-color: #CC0000;

a {
    color: @link-color;
}
```

"compiles" to

```
CSS

a {
    color: #CC0000;
}
```

**2) Nesting**

```
LESS

.article {
   a {
     text-decoration: underline;
   }

   p {
     margin: .5ex .5em;
   }
}
```

"compiles" to

```
CSS

.article a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.article p {
  margin: .5ex .5em;
}
```

3) **Mixins**

```
LESS

.box-shadow(@style, @color)
{
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @color;
  box-shadow:         @style @color;
}

div
{
  .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%);
}
```

"compiles" to

```
CSS

div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 30%;
}
```

4) **Functions**

```
LESS

@text-color: #000;

.article {
   p {
     color: lighten(@text-color);
   }
}
```

"compiles" to

```
CSS

.article p {
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
```